# Is relogging very often considered as cheating?

Tags: pokemon-go

I often feel like the App suspends and so I "wish" it away in Task Manager (Double Home Button on iPhone or Right Button on Android). When I relaunch the App my Avatar has to be find its position again and "bounces around" (This effect seems to be stronger inside buildings).

On this way I often face Pokémon instantly after relogging. Is this just imagination or is it maybe even handled as cheating due to the quick location change? Does anyone have similar experiences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no advantage to logging out and logging back in to Pokémon Go. As a result, you will not be marked as a cheater. The "bouncing around" can happen regardless of how recently you logged in, and would be interpreted as a "hardware fault", so to speak. Not an exploit.

I have previously had a lot of issues with GPS in the game, and found a fix that involved having to completely shut down the game. I do this quite a lot, and do not notice any sudden appearance of Pokémon, when I get back into the game. At the very least, the action of logging in is not spawning more Pokémon.

*If this was actually a bug that caused more Pokémon to spawn*, you would consider it an "exploit". For further confidence, rest assured that "exploiting an exploit" requires deliberation and intentional understanding. The simple fact that you are closing the application to fix an apparent lock-up is enough to determine that *even if this was giving you an advantage*, you would not typically be defined as cheating.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you simply minimize the app and not shut it down entirely (you're not killing it in the task manager or anything) ? In any case this is not cheating, this is the GPS trying to figure out where in the world you are, as the phone and the satellites talk few times a second - constantly, and you suddenly stopped all the chatter, now your phone is not really sure where it is, and it needs a moment to figure this stuff out.

So **NO** it's in no way cheating whatsoever.

Comment: Yes but can you answer the part if its really an advantage to relog due to the toggling of the character? Maybe this point didnt come theough in my question